# Chome extension to highlight text in text files based on multiple regex?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I am looking for a Chrome extension that I can use to colorize text files based on multiple regular expressions?

I am quite often looking at text log files and it would be very helpful to be able to highlight errors on them.

Answer (score 1):

[Highlight This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/highlight-this/fgmbnmjmbjenlhbefngfibmjkpbcljaj?hl=en-US) looks pretty promissing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Rex - RegEx Highlight or Collapse Text](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rex-regex-highlight-or-co/eejlhekkafpkffbhpidchepheodkgnib)

I've found it very useful for regex hightlighting and log analyzing.

It supports full regex while [Hightlight this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/highlight-this/fgmbnmjmbjenlhbefngfibmjkpbcljaj?hl=en-US) only supports `*` and `?` wildcards.

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?